# Counter Help VBA

Tags: excel, vba, counter

I recently made the code below which reads the values inside certain columns and verifies if they are all on the same row and increments if the combination is the same as the one defined
But now i want to add another feature to it and im not sure how to go about doing it which is why i need help
Basically there is column G in my second sheet(same sheet that receives all the other values) that receives dates in the format "dd/mm/yyyy" and i would like it so that depending on the week number associated with said date the counter would be placed in a different row in sheet15.

for example lets say that there are only these 5 rows filed in the columns i defined and these are the values present in that sheet :

[Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7GKv.png)

i would want there to be 2 counters,1 for the row with : 1, 2, 3, 3/2/0, 28/09/2023 and 1, 2, 3, 3/1/0, 29/09/2023 and another counter for 1, 2, 3, 3/1/0, 05/06/2023
the first counter would have the number 2 being displayed because 2 rows have the correct combination and they share the same weeknumber associated with their dates and the other counter would have 1 because there's only one row present with the correct combination of values that has the same weeknumber
i also would want the counters to be displayed in the same row number as their weeknumber so the first counter i mentioned would be displayed in row 39 and the other one would be displayed in row 23
Im sorry if what im asking here is confusing,if you have any question ask away and ill try my best to answer

I tried the following code but i am unable to make a part for the dates

```
Sub Button1_Click() 'Leaks
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim countRange As Range
    Dim count As Long
    Dim searchValue1 As String
    Dim searchValue2 As String
    Dim searchValue3 As String
    Dim searchValue4 As Variant ' Change the data type to Variant
   
    ' Define the search range in Sheet2 where you want to look for the data combination
    Set searchRange = Sheet2.Range("B1:H" & Sheet2.Cells(Rows.count, "H").End(xlUp).row) ' Modify the range as per your data
   
    ' Define the range in Sheet15 where you want to store the count
    Set countRange = Sheet15.Range("P1") ' Modify the cell as per your preference
   
    ' Clear previous count
    countRange.value = ""
   
    ' Define the search values (combination of data)
    searchValue1 = "1"
    searchValue2 = "2"
    searchValue3 = "3"
    searchValue4 = Array("3/1/0", "3/2/0") ' Modify the values as per your requirement
   
    ' Convert the search range to a variant array for faster processing
    Dim dataArr As Variant
    dataArr = searchRange.value
   
    ' Loop through the array to search for the combination of values
    Dim i As Long
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim foundCount As Long
   
    numRows = UBound(dataArr, 1)
   
    For i = 1 To numRows
        ' Check if each search value is found in the row
        If dataArr(i, 1) = searchValue1 And _
           dataArr(i, 2) = searchValue2 And _
           dataArr(i, 3) = searchValue3 And _
           IsValueInArray(dataArr(i, 7), searchValue4) Then ' Use a helper function to check if value is in array
            foundCount = foundCount + 1
        End If
    Next i
   
    ' Store the count in the count range of Sheet15
    countRange.value = foundCount
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Private Function IsValueInArray(value As Variant, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    ' Helper function to check if value is in array
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        If value = arr(i) Then
            IsValueInArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
    IsValueInArray = False
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used Worksheet objects since I didn't feel like creating 14 extra worksheets to test it out and this is "best practice" anyway ^^ (might need to adjust it if your sheets are named differently)

```
Sub Button1_Click() 'Leaks
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
   
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim countRange As Range
    Dim count As Long
    Dim searchValue1 As String
    Dim searchValue2 As String
    Dim searchValue3 As String
    Dim searchValue4 As Variant ' Change the data type to Variant
    Dim wkArray, wkNum As Integer
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, ws15 As Worksheet
    
    ReDim wkArray(1 To 52, 1 To 1)
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set ws15 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet15")
   
    ' Define the search range in Sheet2 where you want to look for the data combination
    Set searchRange = ws2.Range("B1:H" & ws2.Cells(Rows.count, "H").End(xlUp).Row) ' Modify the range as per your data
   
    ' Define the range in Sheet15 where you want to store the count
    Set countRange = ws15.Range("P1") ' Modify the cell as per your preference
   
    ' Clear previous count
    countRange.value = "" 'could just use .ClearContents
   
    ' Define the search values (combination of data)
    searchValue1 = "1"
    searchValue2 = "2"
    searchValue3 = "3"
    searchValue4 = Array("3/1/0", "3/2/0") ' Modify the values as per your requirement
   
    ' Convert the search range to a variant array for faster processing
    Dim dataArr As Variant
    dataArr = searchRange.value
   
    ' Loop through the array to search for the combination of values
    Dim i As Long
    Dim numRows As Long
    Dim foundCount As Long
   
    numRows = UBound(dataArr, 1)
   
    For i = 1 To numRows
        ' Check if each search value is found in the row
        If dataArr(i, 1) = searchValue1 And _
           dataArr(i, 2) = searchValue2 And _
           dataArr(i, 3) = searchValue3 And _
           IsValueInArray(dataArr(i, 7), searchValue4) Then ' Use a helper function to check if value is in array
            foundCount = foundCount + 1
            wkNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(DateValue(dataArr(i, 5)), vbMonday)
            wkArray(wkNum, 1) = wkArray(wkNum, 1) + 1
        End If
    Next i
   
    ' Store the count in the count range of Sheet15
    countRange.value = foundCount
    ws15.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(wkArray, 1)) = wkArray
   
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

The function remained the same.
The wkArray is to be able to paste it in one go after we're done checking everything. I've tested this and it works after placing your "3/1/0" values to the H-column since your test-pic wouldn't have worked with the given code.
Let me know if you have any issues :)

Comment: First off all i just wanted to thank you for taking the time to try and help me
The code is indeed working and it is pretty much what i need! 
but i do have a question,is it checking the dates and seeing if they share the same weeknumber and then placing the counter to its respective row or is it checking the values in column "H"?

Im asking this because i tried the code and there's 3 counters present,one that i assume is the total counter in column P
and 2 others,for me one of them had 4 (in column H there were 4 "3/1/0") and the other one had 1 (in column H there was a single "3/2/0")

Comment: From what I understood from your question, you only wanted Week-counter to go up one if the respective date had all the searchValues correctly. Your test-data had to be modified a little since you used `dataArr(i,7)` with 7 being column H, the dates are in `dataArr(i,5)`. So let me know in case I misunderstood when to count the weeknumbers.

Comment: hmmm
basically i wanted the counter to go up when all the searchvalues were correct.
This means that the order could be 1-2-3-3/1/0- *date* or 1-2-3-3/2/0- *date* and it would increment in same cell IF these dates shared the same weeknumber.
If they share different weeknumbers then one counter will go to the row with the same number as the date's weeknumber (ex: weeknumber 26 = row 26) and the other one will go to the row that is the same as its date's weeknumber

Im sorry if this is confusing,im not the best at explaining things!

Comment: No problem, I have the same issue with explaining things :) However, that's exactly how I have the code in my answer, it's in the `If dataArr(i,1) = searchValue1 And _ .....` clause and updates that week number in the wkArray if all of that is true. So I believe you'll have to adjust the dataArr to account for where your data is in. Since in your question you have it like `1, 2, 3, 3/2/0, 28/09/2023` making the date `dataArr(i,5)` and the 3/2/0 `dataArr(i,4)` but in your code it's `dataArr(i,7)` (with your searchrange from B:H, aka 1 to 7). Hope that helps.